# SCHEME: How to evaluate an arithmetical expression

Tags: recursion, scheme

In scheme - how can I evaluate a simple expression (containing only + * - / () and 0-9 digits) given as a string?

I've tried to first turn the expression into a postfix expression but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this parser for infix expressions.

http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/soegaard/infix.plt/1/0/planet-docs/manual/index.html

Here is a small example (it takes a while for the library to install - it seems the old Schematics test suite takes forever to install these days - I need to switch to a builtin one).

```
#lang at-exp racket
(require (planet soegaard/infix)
         (planet soegaard/infix/parser))
(display (format "1+2*3 is ~a\n" @${1+2*3} ))

(parse-expression #'here (open-input-string "1+2*3"))
```

The output will be:

```
1+2*3 is 7
.#<syntax:6:21 (#%infix (+ 1 (* 2 3)))>
```

The function parse-expression parses the expression in the string and
returns a syntax-object that resembles the output of ToExpression.